# Creating dummy variables before or after splitting to train/test datasets

Tags: modeling, validation, categorical-encoding

I have a data set with a few columns of categorical type. As part of modelling process, I need to convert them into dummy variables. My confusions is whether to do dummy creation before or after splitting the data into train/test data sets.

1. If I do before splitting, doesn't it mean data leakage ? i.e exposing at least a portion of test data to train data ?
2. If I do it after splitting, what if some levels in train are not in test & vice versa ? If that level (for eg: country_AU) is a predictor variable in the final model trained on the train data, won't it throw error if it couldn't find that predictor in the test data set ?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You gotta do it before splitting the data into train and test. There is no data leakage when u do preprocessing. The leakage will happen only when u expose the test data to your model, which has nothing do with the preprocessing phase.

Comment: This is true as long as in your preprocessing nothing is learned from the data itself.  Making dummies is not data dependent, it is just an application of a fixed transformation.  But standardizing, for example, is a preprocessing step that must be handled delicately, since it involves learning the mean and variance of the features in the data.

Comment: It is always tricky to do data pre-processing like missing value imputation, outlier treatment without looking at the complete data. If we really want a pure untouched data set for validation (as we expect to face such data sets in the real world post production), we should separate out a test data set at the very beginning itself. If we do some transformation together & then split, we can't really call them 100% untouched (at least as per my belief).